# Can i return if condition in the true value of if condition in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: More Explaining picture]

I WANNA AD AN IF CONDITION IN THE IF THE CONDITION IS TRUE PLACE
LIKE :
IF (G5> 0, IF(G5 > 6, "BIG", "SMALL"), "")

[image: THIS IS WHAT I AM TRYING TO CALCULATE]
=IF(G5>0, IF(D6>0, IF(G5>D6, G5-D6, 0), G5+E6),IF(D6<0,IF(E6>F5, E6-F5, 0),0))

Comment: That's possible, but where do you get stuck? Also typing with caps on appears as if you are shouting. Not a nice way to ask a question.

Comment: You type a formula containing `G5` and say you'd expect the outcome there. A formula can't refer to it's own outcome, it is calculating that to get there. Further on your picture doesn't show columns or row numbers, so it's hard to see what you mean, or trying to get at.

Comment: sorry my caps was lock and i didn't notice it until it was to late, anyway i'm going to add a picture to make myself more clear

Comment: Can you explain why you expect it to calculate 8000?

Comment: it's an economy formula

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(D2>89,"A",IF(D2>79,"B",IF(D2>69,"C",IF(D2>59,"D","F"))))
```

If the Test Score (in cell D2) is greater than 89, then the student gets an A

If the Test Score is greater than 79, then the student gets a B

If the Test Score is greater than 69, then the student gets a C

If the Test Score is greater than 59, then the student gets a D

Otherwise the student gets an F

Source:https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-nested-formulas-and-avoiding-pitfalls-0b22ff44-f149-44ba-aeb5-4ef99da241c8

Answer (score 0):

`IFS` checks for multiple conditions and returns the value of the first found TRUE. In your case no TRUE is found (G5 is not greater than D6) and returns N/A

Answer (score 0):

In your case, G5 is `6000` and D6 is `7000`.
So all conditions are `FALSE` in your `IFS()` formula and it returns `#N/A`.
To provide a value if all your conditions are `FALSE`, you can enter `TRUE` as a final condition, followed by a value.

```
=IFS(AND(G5>0, D6>0, G5>D6), G5-D6, AND(G5>0, D6<=0), E6+G5, AND(G5<=0, D6<=0, E6<F5), E6-F5, TRUE, 0)
```

Comment: Nice workaround. IFERROR would do also and for readability might be more logic